# Unable to access the promise returned

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, promise

New to AngularJS.

I'm trying to get data from a JSON file through `$http` and `$q` and append the data to the view.

But I'm unable to do it. Only 3 `li` elements are created whereas the JSON data has 6 records.

I want to do this using a promise, but it's not working.

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1bThLFPi8TnXmZ2c9PRP?p=preview) demonstrates the issue.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="dataCont">        
    <input type="text" name="text-field" id="text-field"/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="msg in messages">                
            {{ msg.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**App.js :**

```
"use strict";
var App = angular.module('app', []);

App.controller('dataCont', function($scope, messageData) {
    $scope.messages = messageData.getMessageData();
    // console.log($scope.messages);
})
```

**Services.js :**

```
App.factory('messageData', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getMessageData: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            })

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ to learn how promises work.

Comment: I sense an incoming [antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the data from the resolved promise using `then()`...

```
messageData.getMessageData().then(function (data) {
    $scope.messages = data;
}, function (errorStatus) {
    $scope.errorStatus = errorStatus;
});
```

You can also simplify the service a bit by using the promise returned by $http...

```
App.factory('messageData', function($http) {
    return {
        getMessageData: function() {
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'})
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }, function(errorResponse) {
                    throw errorResponse.status;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well. I just went through `AngularJS Fundamentals` from pluralsight. And in that video he doesn't use `.then()` to get the success data. I've just replicated what he did. And it's working for him. But not to me. I'll give this a try too.

Comment: What does the `.success` does then?

Comment: Sorry that didn't help me out either. But 5 `li` elements were created.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now. But can you let me know why my code didn't work and where as the same code did work in the video. You got any idea?

Comment: OK answer updated. `.then` returns the response object, and therefore we need to access the `data` property. `.success` is a shortcut method for accessing the data.

Comment: Through that method which I did, I got the promise object but I wasn't able to access the object. And in the answer you provided. You didn't the `$q` and also you didn't define any `defer()` either.

Comment: I have the `services.js` with the code what I've written and in the controller I used the code what you've posted. It's working fine. My promise was working fine but I was incorrectly accessing the data. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No worries! $http returns a promise, so in my answer we're just leveraging the same promise instead of using $q to create another (which in many cases is unnecessary and is an antipattern, see Bergi's comment above).

Comment: Yes... with the link provided. I do see that my code has some unnecessary codes too. Thanks a lot. Will understand and follow your code.